# What will be installed Windows or Ubuntu on Factory data reset on pre-windows machine?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series which had Windows 10 Preinstalled but I love Ubuntu so I have installed Ubuntu 20 LTS.

My question is what if I do factory data rest to this machine, what will be installed Ubuntu or Windows by Ubuntu by default?

Comment: What do you mean by factory reset here? Do you mean resetting at OS level, for example, from Windows settings?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you wonder what will happen if you make the Dell factory reset from the Dells boot options menu:
If you installed Ubuntu alongside Windows  - therefore leaving the preexisting partitions untouched then the Dell factory reset will most likely bring Windows 10 back. If the recovery partition (do you have a hidden partition?) doesn't exist anymore then probably no reset will take place. The factory reset of your Dell will in no case bring Ubuntu back if the preinstalled OS was Windows.